# Allow call (and maps, and mail) in cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-maps

I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm trying to make a call after people press 'Call' from a popup. Funny thing is, that it goes straight to calling when they click the phone number. But when they hit 'Call', console returns:

`ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='tel:06-83237516`

Code:

Controller:

```
$scope.callPerson = function() {
    var link = "tel:" + $scope.person.phonenumber;
    var confirmTel = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: $scope.person.phonenumber,
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        okText: 'Call'
    });
    confirmTel.then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
            window.open(link);
        } else {
            console.log('cancel call');
        }
    });
}
```

Config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

html:

```
<div ng-click="callPerson()"> {{person.phonenumber}}</div>
```

With Mail, it doesn't work at all, and returns an identical error.
Same for opening maps. It does work in the PhoneGap test app, but not when deployed.

Maps code:

```
$scope.openmaps = function() {
    var address = $scope.person.adres + ", " + $scope.person.plaats;
    var url = '';
    if (ionic.Platform === 'iOS' || ionic.Platform === 'iPhone' || navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
        url = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(address);
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
        url = "geo:?q=" + encodeURIComponent(address);
    } else {
        url = "http://maps.google.com?q=" + encodeURIComponent(address);
    }
    window.open(url);
};
```

Comment: Try  document.location.href = 'tel:'+$scope.person.phonenumber;

Comment: That might work! However, I found something; adding <allow-navigation href="*" /> to the config.xml did the trick (instead of <access origin="*"/>). Don't know why that is.. Maybe because I try to call the url from a controller?

Comment: for me it is working fine in android but not working in iOS any help?

Answer (score 4):

May be it is too late but I want to comment so that other users couldn't face this issue.
Because I didn't find any working solution anywhere.

You need to add
`<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />` in config.xml

I was facing same issue for mailto intent. It was working when I tried it directly

```
<a onclick="mailto:test@me.com">Email</a>
```

But I got an error when I tried to call it using javascript `window.location.href = 'mailto:test@me.com`

`internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='mailto:test@me.com'`

All you need to is to add allow-navigation in your config.xml

So your config.xml will be:

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>    
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />
```

Comment: Adding `<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />` in config.xml makes it work on iOS but break its on Android, which works fine without that line. Quite a dilemma.

Comment: @DavidPrieto you should be able to add it only under the `<platform name="ios">`, so that it does not break on Android.

Answer (score 3):

I use this config in config.xml
for ios

```
    <allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
```

for android

```
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
```

Comment: This partially solved my problems, i've to add target="_system" to the links also

Answer (score 1):

Altering [Cordova's WhiteListPlugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) in `config.xml` did not work for me -- `<access >,``. I tried many combinations, including those above. Doesn't mean these won't work necessarily, just for my setup it doesn't.  (Building for Browser, Android, and iOS)

However, using the [Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) worked:

**Use the inAppBrowser plugin and set the target to _system.**
`cordova.InAppBrowser.open('tel:123456789', '_system');`

This by passes the issues I was seeing in iOS with `unsupported url`, and launches the native system's web browser (i.e., Does not rely on WhiteListPlugin to allow the URL call).

Hope this helps.

Cordova version 6.3.1.